# complete sync between iphone sqlite3 database to sql server 2005 database on the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlite, data-migration

I hava a sqlite3 database placed in the documents folder. I need to sync this database with the sql server 2005, which is running at our server.

Is there a possibility that i can do a Replication between a sqlite3 database and a MSSql server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Are you married to sqlite3? Because the short answer, to the best of my knowledge is not really- with 3 potential options:

1. I've heard of some savvy programmers having a bit of luck writing their own code either using delimited text or XML or the SqlClient provider for .NETCF to move data between the server and sqlite3 database.
2. You can do snapshot replication to any ODBC data source. But this might mean either copying your sqlite database to your server or finding another replication product which can go between SQLite and an ODBC desktop database.
3. The last option I can think of is to switch from sqlite3 to sql mobile edition / sqlce or sql express (depending on if this is a device or something else) as you would have the option to set up replication or RDA (remote data access) between the those databases and your ms sql server 2005 db- hence the question are you married to sqlite3?
4. Also- I just was reading about [SQL Anywhere](http://www.sybase.com/developer/mobile/sqlanywhere/ultralite) (ultralite) from Sybase which is a free solution. This little database has a pretty small footprint and also support MobiLink Synchronization Wizard which allows you to setup replication with your MS 2005 db. Here is a moderately useful article about [MobiLink Synchronization](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database-Code/MobiLink-Synchronization-Wizard-in-SQL-Anywhere-10/).

if you decide to consider option 3 here are some articles to help set up [RDA](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/01/06/sqlce20.html?page=2) or [Replication](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-ce/3730/Merge-Replication-MS-SQL-CE-3-5-SQL-SERVER-2005) with your db's.

Answer (score 1):

It's not plug-n-play but the Microsoft Sync Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753) will do it.

I've downloaded and installed the iPhone to SQL Server sync sample and run it.  It's actually pretty slick,  Works great.  It was just a basic test but perhaps it will help you.